# Why does my router send an NTP request to ntp.nasa.gov?

Tags: networking, router, time, ntp

I have enabled logging on my router and restarted it. At the end of the log file it says:

```
Sat, 2000-01-01 02:02:19 - Send out NTP request to ntp.nasa.gov
Wed, 2014-01-15 18:01:39 - Receive NTP Reply from ntp.nasa.gov
```

I know about the stratums and the Network Time Protocol a little bit but is there a specific reason for NASA?

Comment: It may also be that they are using a general catch-all like pool.ntp.org and that the DNS request returned ntp.nasa.gov.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real answer to this question without reading the mind of the engineers who designed and configured the base image for your router, but I would posit that because NASA runs some public (S)NTP servers that are very accurate (atomic) and they are non-commercial, but the agency doesn't have the same stigma as DOD, DOE, USNO, or lately NIST servers, so most people who look would not feel disturbed by NASA knowing they had a host at a given IP address.

I imagine its just about positive optics. I usually use time.nist.gov, but NASA is an equally appealing choice.